SuiteScript 2.0 add button, redirect to form, populate reason field
I am trying to update the value on a record based on a value entered on a custom form when clicking a button. I am using a Suitelet script, User event script, and a Client script to achieve this. Essentially, the user will click the button to reject a bill, record a reason, and then it will populate on the bill and set the rejected status.
I was attempting to use the redirectToSuitelet function but when I click the button I am getting this error 'mod.redirectToSuitelet is not a function' when attempting to click the button, the button does nothing. I also attempted to use placeButtonOrderClick with the same results.
enter image description here
Here is my Suitelet script:
`define(['N/record', 'N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/redirect'], function (record, serverWidget, redirect) {
    function onRequest(context) {
        if (context.request.method === 'GET') {
            var form = serverWidget.createForm({ title: 'Enter Reject Reason' });
            form.addField({
                id: 'custpage_reject_reason',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXTAREA,
                label: 'Reject Reason'
            }).isMandatory = true;

            form.addSubmitButton({ label: 'Submit' });

            form.addField({
                id: 'custpage_bill_id',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
                label: 'Bill ID'
            }).updateDisplayType({ displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.HIDDEN }).defaultValue = context.request.parameters.billId;

            context.response.writePage(form);
        } else {
            var rejectReason = context.request.parameters.custpage_reject_reason;
            var billId = context.request.parameters.custpage_bill_id;

            var billRecord = record.load({
                type: record.Type.VENDOR_BILL,
                id: billId
            });

            billRecord.setValue({
                fieldId: 'custbody_reject_reason',
                value: rejectReason
            });

            billRecord.save();

            redirect.toRecord({
                type: record.Type.VENDOR_BILL,
                id: billId
            });
        }
    }

    return {
        onRequest: onRequest
    };
});`

Here is my User Event Script:
`define(['N/url', 'N/ui/serverWidget'], function (url, serverWidget) {
    function beforeLoad(context) {
        if (context.type === context.UserEventType.VIEW) {
            var form = context.form;
            var billId = context.newRecord.id;

            var suiteletURL = url.resolveScript({
                scriptId: 'customscript_reject_reason_code',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_reject_reason_code',
                params: { billId: billId }
            });

            form.addButton({
                id: 'custpage_reject_button',
                label: 'Send Back to AP',
                functionName: 'redirectToSuitelet'
            });

            form.clientScriptFileId = '1128350'; // Ensure this is the correct file ID from the File Cabinet
        }
    }

    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad
    };
});`

Here is my Client script:
`define(['N/url', 'N/log'], function (url, log) {
    function redirectToSuitelet() {
        var billId = nlapiGetRecordId();
        var suiteletUrl = nlapiResolveURL('SUITELET', 'customscript_reject_reason_code', 'customdeploy_reject_reason_code', null) + '&billID =' + billId;
        window.location.href = suiteUrl;
    }
    log.debug('Redirecting to Suitelet', suiteletUrl);  // Add logging for debugging
});

return {
    redirectToSuitelet: redirectToSuitelet
};`

Am I not linking the scripts together properly or is there another function I should be using when attempting to redirect to the Suitelet?
Thanks!

It looks like an issue with your User Event Script
How to call Form.clientScriptFileId using internal Id you can see the example provided by the Oracle document
form.clientScriptFileId = 1128350;

Or
You can pass the path
form.clientScriptFileId = 'SuiteScripts/yourClient_script.js';

Or
if both the UserEventScript file and client Scripts are sorted in the same folder
form.clientScriptModulePath = './yourClient_script.js';

